# Audio Unit File Reader with AudioFileID and Encrypted File

Tags: macos, objective-c++, audiounit

I am reading in and playing audio files in MacOS using Audio Unit Generator `AudioFilePlayer`

```objectivec
AudioComponentDescription fileplayercd = {0};
fileplayercd.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Generator;
fileplayercd.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_AudioFilePlayer;
fileplayercd.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
AUNode fileNode;
AUGraphAddNode(graph, &fileplayercd, &fileNode);
```

and setting its source file with

```objectivec
CFURLRef inputFileUrl =CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(kCFAllocatorDefault, INPUT_FILE_LOCATION, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, false);
AudioFileID inputFile;
AudioFileOpenURL(inputFileUrl, kAudioFileReadPermission, 0, &inputFile)
AUGraphNodeInfo(graph, fileNode, NULL, fileAU);
AudioUnitSetProperty(fileAU, kAudioUnitProperty_ScheduledFileIDs, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &inputFile, sizeof(inputFile))
```

but my real audio files are all encrypted so I cannot use a raw `AudioFileID`. Instead, I need to somehow extend the ID and insert the decrypt code before any "real" reads. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished using `AudioFileOpenWithCallbacks` with parameters for read getsize callbacks.

```
OSStatus result = AudioFileOpenWithCallbacks((__bridge void*)audioData, readProc, 0, getSizeProc, 0, 0, &inputFile);
```

Details on usage can be found in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17504993/converting-mp3-to-aac-using-audio-file-initialize-with-callbacks).